# Large prime divisors of values of a polynomial, in a given residue class

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, polynomials

Let $f(X) \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ be an irreducible polynomial of degree $d \geq 2$. Let $q \in \mathbb{N}$ be an integer, and let $q \mathbb{Z} + r$ be a residue class that contains infinitely many primes $p$ such that $f$ has $d$ roots modulo $p$. I would like to find primes $p \equiv r \bmod q$ such that $p \mid f(n)$, where $n$ is small compared to $p$. Of course, we can take $0 \leq n < p$, but I would like to go a step further.

**Question:** Is it true that for each constant $\varepsilon > 0$ and each sufficiently large $N \in \mathbb{N}$, with notation as above, we can find a prime $N \leq p < (1+\varepsilon)N$ and an integer $0 \leq n < \varepsilon p$ such that $p \mid f(n)$?

What is known:

- In *[A lower bound on the LCM of polynomial sequences](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1910.13218.pdf)* by Maynard and Rudnick, the authors show (Cor. 3.2) that for a positive proportion of integers $n$, the value $f(n)$ is divisible by a prime $p$ with $p \gg_d n \log n$. This is very similar to the statement that I'm looking for, in a much stronger quantitative form (i.e., with $1/\log n$ in place of $\varepsilon$, more or less). Unfortunately, the techniques of Maynard and Rudnick do not seem to allow us to restrict $p$ to a residue class modulo $q$.
- In *[Roots of quadratic congruences](https://academic.oup.com/imrn/article-abstract/2000/14/719/667937?redirectedFrom=PDF)* by Tóth, based on [Equidistribution of Roots of a Quadratic Congruence to Prime Moduli](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2118527) by Duke, Friedlander and Iwaniec (cf. *[On roots of quadratic congruences](https://arxiv.org/abs/2107.13301)* by Ngo), it is shown that in the case where $\deg f = 2$, the roots of $f$ modulo primes $p \equiv r \bmod q$ are equidistributed (i.e., if we order all pairs $(p,n)$ where $p \equiv r \bmod q$ is a prime and $0 \leq n < p$ satisfies $p \mid f(n)$ in the lexicographical order then the ratios $n/p$ are equidistributed in $[0,1]$). In particular, it follows that we can find pairs $(p,n)$ with $n/p \in (0,\varepsilon)$, as needed.

Further comments:

- The question is motivated by work on decision problems involving hypergeometric sequences with J. Worrell, M. Shirmohammadi and G. Kenison and A. Scoones. I'm happy to discuss more details, if relevant.
- I expect that a full answer might be out of reach, but it would still be very interesting to know about any special cases. For instance: What if $f$ is a cyclotomic polynomial?
- Effective results are particularly interesting. In other words, it would be best if it's possible to compute, at least in principle, an admissible value of $N$ as a function of $\varepsilon$ and $f$. (I believe that this is the case in degree $2$ but details still need to be checked.)